# C++ Type Overloading only partly functional?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm currently trying to create a universal string stream class that I can use as e.g. a parameter in functions to conjoin values without too much work.

There just seems to be a weird oddity I am facing right now.

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExStream.h"

using namespace std;

void func1(string);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ExStream ex;
    ex << "Hey";
    func1(ex);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void func1(string s) {
    cout << "func1 " << s << endl;
}
```

**ExStream.h**

```
#ifndef EXSTREAM_H
#define EXSTREAM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class ExStream {

private:
    string val;

    string toString(int);
    string toString(char);
    string toString(char*);
    string toString(const char*);
public:
    ExStream();

    friend ExStream& operator+(ExStream&, ExStream);
    friend ExStream& operator+(ExStream&, int);
    friend ExStream& operator+(ExStream&, char);
    friend ExStream& operator+(ExStream&, char*);
    friend ExStream& operator+(ExStream&, const char*);
    friend ExStream& operator+(ExStream&, string);

    friend ExStream& operator<<(ExStream&, ExStream);
    friend ExStream& operator<<(ExStream&, int);
    friend ExStream& operator<<(ExStream&, char);
    friend ExStream& operator<<(ExStream&, char*);
    friend ExStream& operator<<(ExStream&, const char*);
    friend ExStream& operator<<(ExStream&, string);

    operator char*();
    operator const char*();
    operator string();

    void out();
};

#endif
```

**ExStream.cpp**

```
#include "ExStream.h"

ExStream::ExStream() {

}

ExStream& operator+(ExStream& ex1, ExStream ex2) {
    ex1.val.append(ex2.val);
    return ex1;
}

ExStream& operator+(ExStream& ex, int i) {
    ex << ex.toString(i);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator+(ExStream& ex, char c) {
    ex << ex.toString(c);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator+(ExStream& ex, char* s) {
    ex << ex.toString(s);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator+(ExStream& ex, const char* s) {
    ex << ex.toString(s);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator+(ExStream& ex, string s) {
    ex.val.append(s);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator<<(ExStream& ex1, ExStream ex2) {
    ex1.val.append(ex2.val);
    return ex1;
}

ExStream& operator<<(ExStream& ex, int i) {
    ex << ex.toString(i);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator<<(ExStream& ex, char c) {
    ex << ex.toString(c);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator<<(ExStream& ex, char* s) {
    ex << ex.toString(s);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator<<(ExStream& ex, const char* s) {
    ex << ex.toString(s);
    return ex;
}

ExStream& operator<<(ExStream& ex, string s) {
    ex.val.append(s);
    return ex;
}

ExStream::operator char*() {
    return const_cast<char*>(val.c_str());
}

ExStream::operator const char*() {
    return val.c_str();
}

ExStream::operator string() {
    return val;
}

string ExStream::toString(int i) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}
string ExStream::toString(char c) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << c;
    return ss.str();
}
string ExStream::toString(char* s) {
    return string(s);
}

string ExStream::toString(const char* s) {
    return string(s);
}

void ExStream::out() {
    cout << "VAL: " << val << endl;
}
```

From my understanding, the two function calls should be the exact same, but this example shows the opposite.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?
I use Visual Studio 2013 for Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/484b4be76af248ff)

Comment: Neither can I, with a different set of patches to the OPs typos. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daf826a04e3c9007

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to reinvent the wheel, there is already append method which do the same thing you are trying to do. Don't forget that string is not a primitive type in C++ it's an object.

For your problem, it seems that the cast ***(string)ex*** is causing runtime error. may be you should have a look to this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ about casting in C++.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. Couldn't really identify the error due to inexperience. Also, I'm doing this just for training because I haven't used overloaded operators or types yet.

Comment: @Freeman This is a common mistake. **[Don't use C-style casts in C++](https://anteru.net/2007/12/18/200/).** If no other type of conversion works, C-style casts will fall back on `reinterpret_cast` (the most dangerous cast) which is *almost always* the wrong thing, and you'll have *no clue this is what is happening*. In this case it would be triggering undefined behavior; a crash is probably the best outcome you could expect under the circumstances.